# Who is next to bat after a batsman is out?

Tags: rules, cricket

I've been watching this [Big Bash League match](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fV_hE9LQ1Jw) and at 1:19:58 (also in other times too) a batsman is out and a new one is coming in.

However the new batsman isn't facing the bowler immediately ("*on strike"*) at 1:20:56 (see the arrows at the bottom of the screen).

Why is the new batsman not batting, but the partner is? The given over continues, so my conclusion is that the new batsman should bat.

Comment: What @PhilipKendall said: this would occur if the batsmen crossed before a catch was taken. I'd add that the non-striker would also take strike, with the incoming batsman the non-striker, in the event of a run-out at the non-striker's end while running an odd number of runs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During certain types of dismissals (caught, run-out and obstructing the field), the on-strike batsman after the dismissal is determined based on the position of the not-out batsman on the pitch.

- If they were taking a run and the not-out batsman had **crossed their partner** when the catch was taken or the run out occurred then the **not-out batsman would have to switch ends.**
- On the other hand if the not-out batsman hadn't crossed the middle of the pitch he would have to continue on the same end.

A few examples to understand the same:

- If the batsman on-strike is caught behind and the non-strike batsman hasn't left his crease then the new batsman in takes strike.
- If the batsman on-strike is caught while taking a single and the batsmen have completed a run meanwhile then the not-out batsman takes strike because he has crossed.
- If the batsman on-strike is run-out while completing his second run, the new batsman in takes strike because the not-out batsman is back to his original end.

These rules are described in detail in [Law 18 (Section 11 & 12)](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-18-scoring-runs/).

Section 11:

> **11. Batsman returning to original end**

> (a) When a batsman is dismissed, the not out batsman shall return to his original end

> (i) if the striker is himself dismissed in the circumstances of Law 2.8(d) (Transgression of the Laws by a batsman who has a runner).

> (ii) and, with the three exceptions of

> - Run out other than in (i) above

- Caught
- Obstructing the field,

> for all other methods of dismissal.

Section 12:

> **12. Batsman returning to wicket he has left**

> (a) When a batsman is dismissed Caught, Obstructing the field or Run out other than under Law 2.8, the not out batsman shall return to the wicket he has left but only if the batsmen had not already crossed at the instant of the incident causing the dismissal.

Answer (score 0):

Batsman can change the strike in different ways if the one over complete then the batsman can rotate there strike and if the batsman got catch out then also non-striker batsman can change there strike by running towards the other end.

So, here if you observe in the video, the men's changed their strikes and the new batsman had to be at the other end.